# Angular chosen error with undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

CODE: http://plnkr.co/edit/H2hmEukfjaPL1T4W298O?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="chosen@*" data-semver="1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.min.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.20"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <select chosen ng-model="bar">
      <option>Hi</option>
      <option>This is fun</option>
      <option>I like Chosen so much</option>
      <option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['localytics.directives']);
```

I am not sure why I am getting this:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at http://run.plnkr.co/lPtcBAAKhcfkB6tE/chosen.js:86:26
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:5873:13
>       at Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12608:28)
>       at Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12420:31)
>       at Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:12712:24)
>       at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:1419:15
>       at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:3918:17)
>       at doBootstrap (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:1417:14)
>       at bootstrap (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:1431:12)
>       at angularInit (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js:1344:5)

Any clue?

Comment: Load jQuery before AngularJS.

Comment: Please answer below so i can mark answer. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You need to have jquery before angularjs in this case

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
     <link data-require="chosen@*" data-semver="1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.min.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.20"></script>
 <script src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="chosen.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<select chosen ng-model="bar">
  <option>Hi</option>
  <option>This is fun</option>
  <option>I like Chosen so much</option>
  <option>I also like bunny rabbits</option>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```